# Complex numbers; trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I don't know how to do this:

Show that the equation: $3z^4-z^3+2z^2-z+3=0$, can be written as $6\cos2θ-2\cosθ+2=0$

I don't even know how to start so
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Do you have $|z|$?

Comment: Divide through by $z^2$ and pair off the terms with the same coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equation can be simplified in the given way only if $|z|=1$

$$3z^4-z^3+2z^2-z+3=z^2 \left( 3\left(z^2+\frac {1}{z^2}\right)-\left(z+\frac {1}{z}\right)+2\right)$$

And now write $$\left(z^2+\frac {1}{z^2}\right)=e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}=2\cos 2\theta$$ and $$\left(z+\frac {1}{z}\right)=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=2\cos \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide by $z^2$, so you get
$$
3\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)-\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)+2=0
$$
Notice that
$$
z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}=\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2-2
$$
so, setting $t=z+z^{-1}$ we obtain
$$
3t^2-t-4=0 \tag{*}
$$
which means
$$
t=-1\qquad\text{or}\qquad t=\frac{4}{3}
$$
Denote by $a$ either of these values; then
$$
z^2-az+1=0
$$
In both cases, $|z|=1$, so we can set $z=e^{i\theta}$ and
$$
t=z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\theta
$$
Substitute in (*).